# Executing three functions after each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have three functions that I want to execute after each other. The order is important because func2 depends on data from func1 and func3 from func2. I have used callbacks up until now. I would like to use jQuery.when().then().done(). I cant get my head around the tutorials out there. Some of theme use `var def = jQuery.Deferred();` and others dont. I dont want to use timeouts. Because I dont always now the exact amount of time the functions will take to execute. I would be very grateful if somebody could show me how its done with jQuery.

> Edit

This is how I am doing it right now. But I would like to evolve my knowledge to use something better or more manageable when there is a lot of functions to execute in order.

```
   one(function(){
    two(function (){
    three();
      });
    });


    function one(callback){
    var call = jQuery.ajax({})
    call.done(function(data){callback();})
    }

    function two(callback){
    var call = jQuery.ajax({})
    call.done(function(data){callback();})
    }

    function three(){
    var call = jQuery.ajax({})
    call.done(function(data){})
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you want to execute? You can use promises, async / await etc.

Comment: You can use async package and use waterfall execution or you can use promises.

Comment: Without your code and to see the workflow, it's hard to suggest things

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `then()` is a custom implementation of the `Promises` in Javascript. I recommend using the native version which is supported by most modern browsers. What you want to achieve can be done in two different ways :

### Using `Promise.defer()` (deprecated) :

```
function first() {
    var deferred = Promise.defer();
    doSomethingAsynchronously(function (result) {
        if (result.success)
            deferred.resolve(result.data);
        else
            deferred.reject(result.error);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

### Using `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {})`

```
function second(someData) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        doSomethingElseAsynchronously(someData, function (result) {
            if (result.success)
                resolve(result.data);
            else
                reject(result.error);
        });
    })
}
```

In both cases, you will be able to do this :

```
first().then(function(data) {
    return second(data)
}).then(function(data) {
    return third(data);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Now this is for native Javascript Promises. jQuery's promises might be slightly different but I think that understanding the above explanation about native Promises will help you apprehend tutorials about jQuery's implementation.

Comment: Thank you. This worked great!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle asynchronous  code, you should use promises:

```js
function function1(data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log(1);
    resolve(data + " world");
  });
}

function function2(data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(2);
      resolve(data + " of");
    }, 2000 * Math.random());
  });
}

function function3(data) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(3);
      resolve(data + " coding");
    }, 2000 * Math.random());
  });
}
//Run promise
var promise = function1("hello")
  .then(function2)
  .then(function3)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

**Edit 1 - Put the promises inside the functions**

Comment: You should put the `new Promise` inside the respective function, though

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is simple, it can be done like the following. Why you want to complicate it.

```
function function1(){
  //On completion
  function2(data);
}
function function2(data){
 //On completion 
  function3(newdata);
}
function function3(nedata){
 //Function 3 code here
}
```

Comment: If the code in the first lines of functions1() is asynchronous nothing guarantees that your function will wait for completion before calling function2()

Comment: Just want to learn new ways of doing it, so I am prepaired when I have bigger challanges to overcome